# How to download "https://www.digitimes.com/index.asp" by using requests library in Pycharm and Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

As i have tried using headers, I am getting EOF protocol voilation error. While using proxy i.e. proxy = {'http': 'http://www.blahblah.com'}, I am getting 404 error. I am using Ubuntu.

My code is:

```
proxy = {'http': 'http://www.blahblah.com'}
r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}, proxies = proxy)
```

Comment: You can simplify your question: even `requests.get("https://www.digitimes.com/index.asp")` gives `EOF occurred in violation of protocol`.  I guess the server is broken or doesn't want to be scraped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like browsers are using extended list of ciphers while trying to establish connection. For python you need to use `DES-CBC3-SHA` cipher to download this site:

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS += ':DES-CBC3-SHA'

In [3]: requests.get('https://www.digitimes.com/index.asp')
Out[3]: <Response [200]>
```

For curl you may also specify this cipher:

```
curl -v --cipher DES-CBC3-SHA  https://www.digitimes.com/index.asp
```

Or use `--sslv3` (I have discovered `DES-CBC3-SHA` using `--sslv3`):

```
➜  ~ curl -v --sslv3  https://www.digitimes.com/index.asp
*   Trying 122.255.90.243...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.digitimes.com (122.255.90.243) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /Users/soon/anaconda3/ssl/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* SSLv3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* SSLv3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using SSLv3 / DES-CBC3-SHA
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
... response
```

Comment: Thanks for the support, the second option of curl request worked perfectly.

Comment: Please let me know how to download this sit: https://www.portafolio.co/indicadores-economicos

Comment: It gives following error: raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME] tlsv1 unrecognized name (_ssl.c:645)

Comment: Please post another question